# Access Denied #1045 error after changing phpmyadmin SSL settings to REQUIRE SSL.

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

The errors are as follows:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I have trouble fixing this problem, I've tried the different solutions I've found on the internet especially the one where I had to change my password in  config.inc.php.

It might be worth noting that prior to this error, phpmyadmin was working perfectly fine, and at the time I was getting MySQL to connect to VB.NET and installed the Connector and MySQL for Visual Studio. Furthermore, there was an error about SSL connections while connecting my database to Visual Studio. I did some exploring on my own and changed the settings of my database from NO SSL to REQUIRE SSL. Then the access denied page showed up from there.

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you tell phpMyAdmin to connect via SSL connection by adding `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;` to your config.inc.php? Otherwise, it's still trying to connect via the non-SSL connection method.

Comment: Is there a specific part in the file where I should add that line? Added it in config.inc and a different error showed up: #2006 - mysql server has gone away.